# Reference a created column in the same select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting inconsistent results trying to reference inner columns created previously in the same select.

Can created columns be referenced in the same `select`, `where`, or `having` clause? What are the places it can be referenced and can not be? Thanks for any clarification.

```
select p.fname, p.lname,
case when p.fname = 'dude'
  then 'cool'
  else 'not cool'
end as is_cool
from person p
on p.age > 20
and is_cool = 'cool'
```

or

```
select e.startdate, e.enddate,
case when e.startdate > e.enddate
  then format(dateadd(day, 1, e.enddate), 'M/d/yyyy')
  else format(dateadd(day, 5, e.enddate), 'M/d/yyyy')
end as newdate
case when 'newdate' > e.enddate
  then 'too many'
  else 'not enough'
end as dates
from event e
```

Comment: I assume that `on p.age > 20` is a typo since it should be `where p.age > 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only reference a calculated column in the `order by` clause. For any other use either use a sub-query or repeat the logic.

Sub-query:

```
select PO.fname, PO.lname, PO.is_cool
from (
  select PI.fname, PI.lname, PI.age
    case when PI.fname = 'dude'
      then 'cool'
      else 'not cool'
    end as is_cool
  from dbo.person PI
) PO
where PO.age > 20
and PO.is_cool = 'cool';
```

Repeated Logic:

```
select p.fname, p.lname, 
  case when p.fname = 'dude'
    then 'cool'
    else 'not cool'
  end as is_cool
from dbo.person p
where p.age > 20
-- Same logic as to get 'cool'
and p.fname = 'dude';
```

`Order by` is possible:

```
select p.fname, p.lname, 
  case when p.fname = 'dude'
    then 'cool'
    else 'not cool'
  end as is_cool
from dbo.person p
where p.age > 20
order by is_cool;
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. was thinking there was a way to avoid sub queries especially when many calculated columns are created and cross reference.

Comment: @edtopia there is no reason to avoid sub-queries, they are an essential tool of the trade.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the code a little bit more concise, cross apply can be useful for this kind of thing. You cross apply an expression, or a number of expressions, which you can then refer to by name without having to repeat the entire list of columns, changing aliases, and so on. Especially when you have multiple levels of nesting. That's hard to describe in words, here's an example:

```
select   v.a,
         v.b,
         v.c,
         v.d,
         v.a_plus_b,
         v.a_times_b,         
         v.a_plus_b_squared
from     (
            select u.a,
                   u.b,       
                   u.c,
                   u.d,  
                   u.a_times_b,    
                   u.a_plus_b,
                   a_plus_b_squared = u.a_plus_b * u.a_plus_b
            from   (
                      select t.a,
                             t.b,
                             t.c,
                             t.d,
                             a_times_b = t.a * t.b,
                             a_plus_b = t.a + t.b
                      from   t
                   ) u
 
         ) v
where    v.a_plus_b_squared > 100
order by v.a_times_b
```

That's incredibly verbose compared to this:

```
select      t.a,
            t.b,
            t.c,
            t.d,
            u.a_plus_b,
            u.a_times_b,
            v.a_plus_b_squared
from        t
cross apply (select t.a * t.b, t.a + t.b)    u (a_times_b, a_plus_b)
cross apply (select u.a_plus_b * u.a_plus_b) v (a_plus_b_squared)
where       v.a_plus_b_squared > 100
order by    u.a_times_b
```

Comment: thanks, I was specifically looking for a way to address a calculated column in the same select that created it. appreciate the deets on cross apply, not quite understanding why I can't just use an outer join though.